# How to display custom error message from Node/Express in React/Redux?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, passport.js

I'm using passportjs for user authentication, and in the event that authentication is unsuccessful, I'd like to display a custom error message that is rendered on client side (in this case, React/Redux).

**Route:**

```
app.post(
    '/api/login',
    (req, res) => {
      passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, user, info) => {

        if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'Please verify account first' });

      })(req, res);
    }
  );
```

**Action creator:**

```
export const loginUser = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/login', values);
    dispatch(deleteMessage());
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    history.push('/');
    window.Materialize.toast(`Welcome back ${res.data.local.email}!`, 4000);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  }
}
```

When I catch the error and console log it out however, I get a standard status 400 error message instead of: `{ msg: 'Please verify account first' }`

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Is there a better way to display custom error messages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Modify from `console.log(error)` to `console.log(error.response)` in
>   catch.

ref : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks

Comment: Thank you, looks all over for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the scope of variable **res**, I would suggest the following approach (outside .catch()):

```
if(res.status === 400) {
  const error_msg = res.msg
  dispatch(loginError(error_msg))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('Error:', err);
```

You could change this too whatever error message you want. Or do you want the response `err` from the server to be `{ msg: 'Please verify account first' }`

Comment: Yes I want the response `err` from the server to be `{ msg: 'Please verify account first' }`